# Make an element and put it into a group of elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to make a `div` and put it into all elements that have `.folio-item` class but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: your question can be easily answered by google. If you create your code and stills not being able to success, then create a *real* question here in SO describing your issues

Answer (score -1):

You can use a query selector to get all elements with the class of `folio-item`. You can then use a `for` loop to iterate through those elements and create a `div` to append to those elements with `document.createElement`.

```css
.folio-item{
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="folio-item">
1
</div>
<div class="folio-item">
2
</div>
<div class="folio-item">
3
</div>
<script>
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".folio-item");
for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = "<b style='color: red;'>Appended div</b>";
  div.style.border = "1px solid green";
  div.style.padding = "10px";
  div.style.margin = "5px";
  divs[i].appendChild(div);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service.

Comment: Answering that kind of question only estimulate the creation of many other questions like this one, where the asker didn't show a minimum effort to research about the topic.